# PySpark Dependencies from Windows to Linux Subsystem

Tags: linux, windows, pyspark, dependencies

**SUMMARY**

I have a standalone cluster with 10 physical machines. The master machine is managed in a Linux subsystem on a Windows machine. When I log into the subsystem and submit jobs to the cluster with dependencies, the jobs run without issue. However, when submitting jobs to the subsystem from the Windows machine, I can't seem get the settings tuned correctly to recognize the virutal environment python instance. I've tried to set the PYSPARK_PYTHON variable to the python instance in my virtualenv and I'm using the `--py-files' argument in the spark-submit command to point at a tar.gz file that contains my dependencies. However, I continually get this error:

**ERROR**

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Projects\venv\Scripts\python.exe": error=2, No such file or directory
```

I've confirmed that the python.exe file does indeed live in this path.

**CODE**

The python instance that I'm running lives in a virtual environment located in C:\Projects\venv. When submitting in the subsystem, I'm setting the PYSPARK_PYTHON environment equal to `"./venv/bin/python"` However, the virtual environment in Windows does not have a bin folder, rather a "Scripts" folder. **Here is the job** I'm trying to run with PYSPARK_PYTHON set accordingly:

```
##run.py

import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import os

os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = "C:\Projects\venv\Scripts\python.exe"

def main(spark):
    df = spark.createDataFrame(
        [(1, 1.0), (1, 2.0), (2, 3.0), (2, 5.0), (2, 10.0)],
        ("id", "v"))

    @pandas_udf("double")
    def mean_udf(v: pd.Series) -> float:
        return v.mean()

    print(df.groupby("id").agg(mean_udf(df['v'])).collect())

spark = (
    SparkSession
    .Builder()
    .appName("Dependency Test")
    .master({master_ip_concealed})
    .getOrCreate()
)    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(spark)
```

And here is the submit script (I'm submitting this from the Spark folder location in powershell):

```
spark-submit C:\Projects\test\run.py --py-files C:\Projects\test\pyspark_venv.tar.gz
```

Where the pyspark_venv.tar.gz file is the compressed virtual environment with dependencies generated from running:

```
venv-pack -o pyspark_venv.tar.gz
```

**NOTES**

I'm fairly certain the error is in how I'm defining the PYSPARK_PYTHON environment variable so any assistance in this regard would be greatly appreciated. I need to run this from the Windows machine because I have scripts in a non-test PySpark application that execute Oracle queries and the Oracle drivers are installed on the Windows machine.